# How to install/enable compiz on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, compiz, centos-6

How do I install and/or enable compiz-fusion on CentOS 6? The packages don't appear to be in the repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiz is available in the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository. The package names match their Fedora counterparts, so following [installation instructions for Fedora](http://smashingweb.info/enable-compiz-fusion-on-fedora-14/) should get you going.

Comment: In your answer, could you maybe include some info on how to set it up and install it, like which commands are needed, etc? That would be great!